# Infusionsoft error on add contact (isdk)

Tags: php, api

I'm writing a PHP app that integrates with Infusionsoft. I've googled my error and people seem to be getting it when they pass a string into a function instead of a int. But I don't seem to be doing that. This function takes an Array with string key value pairs.

My Code:

```
$contdata = Array();
foreach($regfields as $key => $value){
     $contdata[str_replace(" ","",$value['name'])] = $answers[$key]);
}

print_r($contdata);

$conID = $app->addCon($contData);
```

The print returns:

```
Array ( [FirstName] => test [LastName] => test [State] => TX [PostalCode] => 77006 [Email] => lovefaithswing@gmail.com )
```

The error:

```
ERROR: -1 - No method matching arguments: java.lang.String, java.lang.String
```

My connection to Infusionsoft is fine since I am able to query for custom fields just previous to this. I thought it was my postal code, but I checked and PostalCode is suppose to be a string (and is).

I tried manually creating the array and that worked fine, so it has something to do with the fact that I'm looping to dynamically create the array.

I added (string) types to both the key and the value to make sure everything is a string. Still didn't work.

Any ideas?

Hailey

Comment: I'm not familiar with Infusionsoft - is it a web service, apache module, or php extension? Do you have a link to the something like a wsdl? That error looks like the "addCon()" method expects other arguments.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out... $contdata, not $contData. Stupid capital D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up realizing that I had a typo. I had $contData when I needed $contdata.